# Filter text in Dataframe column (python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, filter

Does anybody know how to remove such kind of "strange" **characters** from text column in python?

[image]

```
Id  tweet_id    text
13072   13072   1956632973  Okeydokey lol...Night...Love ya too
13073   13073   1754078424  checking out the new web site... i &lt;3
13074   13074   2237729497  human shield à®à®©ï¿½?à®± à®à¯à®±ï¿½?à®¤à¯...
13075   13075   2050423673  OK I think Imma go in the kitchen and attempt ...
13076   13076   2244475952  aww i know i hate when people look sad it's so...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it would be to use a lambda function:

```
df.text.apply(lambda x: ''.join(filter(str.isascii,x)))
```

for larger datasets, regex, e.g., re.sub() is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Apply regular expression **[^\x00-\x7F]** in Text column. This regular expression will remove all the non-ASCII characters from the text.

```
for i in range(len(data['Text'])): 
     Sent=re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]', ' ', data['Text'].iloc[i])
     data['Text'].iloc[i]=Sent
```